# Regression with Measurement Errors in X and Y

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, qq-plot, errors-in-variables

I am trying to find the equation of a line that best fits my data. However, I have errors on the X and Y data points. Here is what my data points look like:

```
   X    x_err       Y         y_err    
-0.120  0.280   0.074484    0.000140
 0.210  0.170   0.091828    0.000414
-0.280  0.300   0.041035    0.002209
```

I came across the `ODR (Orthogonal Distance Regression)` method, this method takes into account that the errors are `normally distributed`. So I did a `Q-Q plot` to check if my errors are normally distributed, here are the plots:

[image: The q-q of the independent variable (X):]

[image: The q-q plot of the dependent variable (Y):]

I can assume that my `independent` variables are `normally distributed`, but I cannot assume this for my `dependent` errors.

**Question 1:** Knowing that my `dependent errors` are not normally distributed, what should the next step be?

**Question 2:** Is it feasible to use ODR to solve my problem?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you say more about what your data *are*? It looks like you have many duplicates of only a few values. Neither are likely to be normally distributed; whether or not they are 'normal enough' is another issue.

Comment: My data represent astronomical data from Kepler, the `independent variable` was measured through observations. The `dependent variable` was fitted according to models (this is why the errors are so small). I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Did you mean to say that Orthogonal Distance Regression allows for the errors to be non-normally distributed instead of "this method takes into account that the errors are normally distributed?"  If your errors are normally distributed, why not just use traditional linear regression?

Comment: Linear regression only requires that your residuals (the difference in your predicted versus actual y values) to be normally distributed.  You could try to transform your data so that the errors are normally distributed or use non-parametric regression like the Theil-Sen method.  Before doing that have you performed a formal test (e.g. Anderson-Darling) on your errors to see if there is evidence that they are not normally distributed?

Comment: @StatsStudent: Linear regression does not require errors to be normal. This seems to be a common misunderstanding. OLS is BLUE etc. without the assumption of normal errors.

Comment: @StatsStudent: Linear regression does not fit my problem because it does not take the error on the measurement into consideration.